# Can't download file with open bootstrap Modal

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have an AngularJS front-end that opens a Bootstrap Modal that has a button on it.  When this button is clicked it calls a Web API method on the server that generates an OPEN XML Word Document as a stream and returns the file to the client.  I have several files downloading successfully in IE where I see this:

[image]

However, for the file I'm trying to download with the open Modal I never see the above image.  It's not the file itself because it downloads successfully when I try it without the open Modal.  Also, I don't see any errors reported in IE Dev Tools.  I don't think it's the code that generates the streams because the same code generates other files successfully.  I also tried closing the Modal before downloading but that didn't work either.  It's almost like the Modal is "blocking" the download.

Here is the Modal definition:

```
    var isOUOModal;
    var isSubmitItem = false;
    var openSignificanceModal = function () {

        return $modal.open({
            scope: $scope,
            templateUrl: './app/oa/significance_modal.html',
            controller: SignificanceModalCtrl,
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                item: function () {
                    return $scope.item;
                }
            }
        });
    };


    var SignificanceModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, item, $window) {
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

     };
```

I seem to be out of ideas at the moment so any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: This does not appear to be the Modal.  Still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine the cause of the problem here. It had to do with the way I was calling the Web API Method. I was using an AJAX JQuery GET call. Instead I had to do something like this:

```
var url = url;
window.location.href = url;
```

When I changed the way I was calling the Web API method I saw the stream returned to the client as expected.